# Optional group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I create an optional non-capturing group in a JavaScript regex?

```
/foo (bar )?bam/ // this does not work for me...
```

I want this to match

```
foo bar bam
```

and

```
foo bam
```

Comment: Your RegEx is working for me! Is it just a minor whitespace issue?

Comment: Your pattern [should be working](http://regexr.com/3caeg). Maybe you're missing the `g`-modifier?

Comment: Actually, I was running this regex in the regex filter in Chrome console and it was not working for me. Not sure of the Chrome console regex format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-capturing group is created with the help of `(?:...)`:

```
foo (?:bar )?bam
     ^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA7fB3/2)

Note that a non-capturing group still *consumes* characters, thus the substring matched with the non-capturing group will still be part of the match.

Snippet:

```js
var res = 'foo bar bam\nfoo bam'.match(/foo (?:bar )?bam/g);
document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```